# How can I use Tikz to place a node given a set of constraints?

Tags: tikz-pgf

Let's say I have 2 nodes. Node 1 is placed anywhere and node 2 is placed right of node 1. Does tikz solve a set of constraints to solve this problem? Clearly it is underdefined as any position on the y axis would satisfy the constraint.

However, if I have 5 nodes

Node 1 is placed at the top.
Node 2 is places below and left of 1.
Node 3 is placed below 2.
Node 4 is placed below and right of 1.
Node 5 is placed right of node 3 and left of node 4.

Where on the y axis is node 5 placed? And could I get both node 4 and 5 to be placed at the same y level as node 3?

Code with ??? for unknown parameters.

```
\node (1) {1};
\node[below left of=1] (2) {2};
\node[below of=2] (3) {3};
\node[below right of 1, ??? and right of 3 ???] (4) {4};
\node[??? right of (3) and left of (4) ???] (5) {5};
```

Also, does tikz know to increase the x spacing between nodes 2 and 4 because I am placing node 5 in between them?

Comment: The first node will be placed at `(0,0)` by default.  You can **not** specify two left, right, above or below options, but you **can** use `at (1 |- 2)` for example.  (Assuming the parser doesn't balk at using numbers for names.)

Comment: First of all, the `… of = …` keys are [deprecated](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/9386) (for over 10 years) and the `positioning` library's `… = of …` should be used. TikZ uses the value of `node distance` or whatever'S written before the `of`, i.e. `below=2cm of 2`. There's no “inbetween” for TikZ. If you need smarter placement, you will need to use the `forest` package or one of the `graphdrawing` libraries.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure about the position specification but this can be done with `positioning` library

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=1mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[draw] (1) {1};
\node[draw, below left= of 1] (2) {2};
\node[draw, below=of 2] (3) {3};
\node[draw, below right= of 1] (4) {4};
\node[draw, right=of 3] (5) {5};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]